# Number of trees which has specific vertex as a leaf?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For vertices ${1,2,...n}$, I want to find the number of trees that has vertex $k$ as a leaf. By Cayley's theorem, the number of total trees are $n^{n-2}$.

designate vertex k as a leaf. Now all trees has at least two leaves so let me pick another leaf and there are n-1 choices.

But there there are so many different possibilities and I'm stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Erase this leaf. You get a labelled tree on $n-1$ vertices , with the labels $\{ 1,2,3,.., k-1, k+1,...,n \}$. Also, keep in mind which of the $k-1$ vertices the leaf is connected to.

Show that you can uniquely reconstruct your tree with leaf $k$ is you know this labeled tree on $n-1$ vertices and the label to which your tree is connected.

Comment: Good thinking, +1!!

Comment: So now I can make $(n-1)^{n-3}$trees with vertices left and I can just connect vertex k to any of the remaining vertices so it will be $(n-1)^{n-2}$?

Comment: @user120227 Yes

Answer (score 2):

Think about the Prüfer code such a tree may have. Take into account that the degree of a vertex is equal to the number of appearances of the vertex inside the Prüfer code plus one.

Therefore you want Prüfer codes where $k$ appears how many times?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't thought about Prufer codes at all!